# What is better for developing app for windows phone 7

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, xna

I am a Dot net C# developer web and desktop apps, recently I have decided to begin development for windows phone 7
from the initial searching on the internet I found that I could user silver-light or XNA Framework for developing on WP7

I do not know any thing about both of them, so do I have to learn both of them to be able to develop WP7 APPS or just one is enough
also Which is better for development if one is enough!

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no good answer for this question if you do not describe application you want to develop. Both technologies are useful for different purposes. I had the same problem with my applications and those my conclusions:

- `Silverlight:` better for business applications when you have small amount of animations (GPU usage)
- `XNA:` high quality games and rich animations

Of course you can use also `Silverlight` for games and `XNA` for business application but generally I spot that it will not work well in most cases.

I first start to implement my application in Silverligh (app with lots of animations) but performance was poor so I decided to switch to XNA. If you want to learn basics of both read `Charles Petzold` [Programming Windows Phone 7](http://www.charlespetzold.com/phone/index.html)

Answer (score 8):

Welcome to WP7 community.
Basically if you want to make event-driven applications, Silverlight is the answer and if your code depends on continuously running loop(like in a game) XNA is the thing.
As u have said dat u develop apps, Silverlight is the light for your question.
You can get lots of samples on net. The official site is http://www.create.msdn.com.

Answer (score 0):

I think Silverlight is easier to start with.
to simplify, Silverlight is intended to be for apps, while XNA is intended to be for games.

Comment: 'easier to start with' completely depends on background. For me, XNA is much easier than Silverlight to tackle, as it's 'code only', no XAML/code behind dichotomy.